# Displaying Specific values in WPF Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

In my combobox i have  added ItemsSource which is a collection of SelectedItem. How to display any item by default in the combobox while loading the screen?

Comment: Bind `SelectedItem` to one of the object in `ItemsSource`. Isn't it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a way to select first item by default? If so, try this code:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="0">
```

Otherwise, you should create a property to store currently selected item and bind to it:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentlySelectedItem}">
```

Comment: i have added like that only. "Items" is my observable collection 1st time it set the value and get the selected item name, but don't know why its hitting second time to the set property and the value is becoming null. So while loading the page the value is not selecting in combobox by deafault.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a binding i.e.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SlowLoadingCollection}"/>
```

then you can add a `FallbackValue` that will be used when the collection cannot be accessed.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SlowLoadingCollection, FallbackValue='Please wait'}"/>
```

you can test this with something like

```
DataContext.SlowLoadingCollection = null; // No collection, so will display fallback
this.OnLoaded += () =>
{
   Task.Run(()=>
   {
      Task.Delay(10000); // 10 second delay to simulate loading
      DataContext.SlowLoadingCollection = new []{ "Hello", "World", "!"};
   }
}
```